# DFP AdManagerAdView times out and returns internal Error code 0

Tags: android, admob, android-webview, ads

I ran into a weird behaviour and have no idea how to solve or debug it. Normally ads work perfectly fine, only when navigating to a webview and back to the app, Ads are not displayed anymore. Any other navigation works perfectly fine (rotation, app in background, different activities and so on) I added logs to the onAdFailed callback and I get a internal error with a latency of 60003 which seems to be a timeout. I checked the requests but there are no requests fired to the adservice.

My question:
is it possible that some webview implementation can affect how ads behave?

would be awesome if you could help me out.

thanks!

com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0

error log:

```
{
      "Code": 0,
      "Message": "Internal error.",
      "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
      "Cause": "null",
      "Response Info": {
        "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
        "Adapter Responses": [
          {
            "Adapter": "com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter",
            "Latency": 60003,
            "Credentials": {},
            "Ad Error": {
              "Code": 0,
              "Message": "Internal error.",
              "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
              "Cause": "null"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally emulator doesn't work well in some admobe formats, but some Notes here:

1-a work around that might help others who have same problem.
in build.gradle app level, change the application  ID with the below line, just for testing.

for Interstitial ads use below:

```
applicationId "com.google.android.gms.example.interstitialexample"
```

for Native advanced , use below:

```
applicationId "com.google.example.gms.nativeadvancedexample"
```

revert back when testing is finished.

if you get a different response, then your code is fine. and mainly the problem is at Admob server side.

2-and/or be sure from using google admob unit ID as below:

```
Banner  "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
Interstitial  "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
Interstitial Video  "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8691691433"
Rewarded Video  "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917"
Native Advanced  "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110"
Native Advanced Video  "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1044960115"
```

3- and for sure, don't forget to try on real device.